# Code wont't work in my version of TeX

Tags: errors

I have this code:

```
\documentclass[seceq]{iis}
%%\documentclass[seceq,review]{iis}

\subjclass{Primary 62F12, Secondary 62F05.}
%A mathematical paper should be accompanied by the Mathematics Subject Classification (MSC) codes.
%Another subject classification codes may be provided. For example, Physics and Astronomy Classification Scheme (PACS), ACM Computing Classification System, JEL (Journal of Economic Literature) codes, and others.

\title{Preparation of Your Manuscripts: A Nice Title Here!}
\runtitle{The short title in the header}

\author{%
\name{First Author \surname{TOHOKU}}$^{1,}$
\CAE{corresponding-author@e-mail.address.here},
\name{Second Author \surname{SENDAI}}$^{2}$
and \name{Third Author \surname{AOBA}}$^{2}$
}
% Provide the authors' names in full.

\inst{$^{1}$Graduate School of Information Sciences, Tohoku University, \address{Sendai 980-8579, Japan}\\
$^{2}$Research Institute of Electrical Communication, Tohoku University, \address{Sendai 980-8577, Japan}}
% Provide the official name(s) of the institutes without abbreviations.

\runauthor{The author(s)' name(s) in the header}

\support{This work is supported by Grant XYZ.}

\recdate{20YY}{0}{DD}%% set by the editors
\accdate{20YY}{0}{DD}%% set by the editors

\abst{A brief abstract of 200 words or less must be set here.
An abstract should state briefly the purpose of the research, the principal results and major conclusions.
The abstract is often presented separately from the article and stored in database,
so it must be able to stand alone and be self-contained.
Also, non-standard or uncommon abbreviations should be avoided,
but if essential they must be defined at their first mention in the abstract itself.}

\kword{\kw{Provide up to five keywords}, \kw{keyword 2}, \kw{keyword 3}, \kw{keyword 4}, \kw{keyword 5}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
\label{Introduction}
...
\end{document}
```

But it won't  work in my version of TeX. I am receiving this message:
`File 'iis.cls' not found`. What I should do and if I need to install a new version of TeX which one should work. I am not familiar with this class.

Comment: `iis.cls` is a non standard latex class. It seems it is a specialised class for a journal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to obtain the non-standard latex class `iis.cls`. A quick search of the text in the abstract tells me that you are trying to prepare a document for the journal [*Interdisciplinary Information Sciences*, published by the Graduate School of Information Sciences, Tohoku University](http://www.is.tohoku.ac.jp/publication/IIS.html).

Somewhere on that website you should find the file `iis.cls`. Download it to your computer.